# python telegram bot registration script

Tags: python, telegram, attributeerror, python-telegram-bot

I was working with python telegram bot --13.15 when I encountered an attribute error from the following code

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler,conversationhandler
from telegram.ext import (
    CommandHandler, CallbackContext,
    ConversationHandler, MessageHandler,
    Filters, Updater, CallbackQueryHandler
)
from key import API_KEY


REGISTRATION,FIRST,AGE=range(3)
def start(bot,update)->int:
    print('user started the bot')    
    user = update.message.from_user
    bot.sendphoto(chatid=update.message.chatid, photo = 'https://icon-library.com/images/bot-icon/bot-icon-5.jpg',caption='Hello {} this is econ bot '.format(user.first_name))

    return REGISTRATION

def register(bot, update):
    bot.sendmessage(chatid=update.message.chatid, text="Welcome! Please enter your name")
    return FIRST  # (1)
def first(bot, update):  # (2)
    user = update.message.from_user
    name = update.message.text
    user.data.user.id = name  # (3)
    reply = "Thanks for registering {}!\n Enter your age".format(name)  # (4)
    bot.sendmessage(chatid=update.message.chatid, text=reply)
    return AGE  # (5)
def age(bot, update):  # (6)  
    age = int(update.message.text)
    user = update.message.from_user
    if age < 18:     # (7)  
      bot.sendmessage(chatid=update.message.chat.id, text="Sorry you are too young to register")   
    else:     
     user.data.user.obj = age     
     bot.sendmessage(chatid=update.message.chat.id, text="Registration successful!")     
     
    return ConversationHandler.END  # (8)



updater = Updater (token=API_KEY, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def main():
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={ REGISTRATION:[MessageHandler(Filters.text,register)],
                FIRST: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, first)],
                AGE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, age)]},
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("start", start)]
        )  # (11)
    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My intentions were to receive user inputs like first name and age where the age is defined by if statements, but it seems to shows attribute error like the one below

```py
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 557, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)  File "C:\Users\bello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\conversationhandler.py", line 627, in handle_update
    new_state = handler.handle_update(update, dispatcher, check_result, context)
  File "C:\Users\bello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 199, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "c:/Users/bello/Desktop/telegram bot/improved test bot1/evolve.py", line 14, in start
    user = update.message.from_user
AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your handler callbacks are defined to take the positional arguments `bot` and `update`. However, you pass `use_context=True` to your `Updater`, which tells `python-telegram-bot` that you define your callbacks to take the positional arguments `update` and `context`. This new style of handler callbacks has been introduced in v12 of `python-telegram-bot` and is the default since v13. v20 removed support for the old-style callbacks. To upgrade your code to a newer version of `python-telegram-bot`, please read the corresponding [transition guides](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki#transition-guides).

Also note that v13.x is no longer maintained by the `python-telegram-bot` team.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.